# « De » déterminant partitif ou préposition ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, déterminants, partitif

Je n’arrive pas à comprendre la différence entre le ‘de’ déterminant partitif et la préposition. J’ai vérifié plusieurs livres de référence sur le sujet sans succès. Par exemple :

> *C’est fait avec de la farine.*

Avec la théorie du remplacement, on peut remplacer les déterminants ‘de la’ avec un déterminant ‘une’, « C’est fait avec ‘une’ farine’ », donc c’est un déterminant.

> *Il vient de France.*

‘De’ ici ne peut être remplacé avec un déterminant, donc c’est une préposition.

Seulement, dans la phrase :

> *C’est une lettre de bêtises.*

On ne peut remplacer par un déterminant mais je doute que ce soit une préposition ici.

Comment: Plus idiomatique: *Cette lettre, c'est un ramassis de bêtises.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Au *TLFi* on peut comparer des exemples d'emploi de la préposition [*de*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de/0) et du partitif [*de*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de/1) en portant une attention particulière aux explications des cas-types (entre crochets) ; c'est d'une grande richesse. Certaines manipulations permettent assurément d'affirmer qu'il s'agit de l'emploi de l'une ou de l'autre...

Une particularité avec l'exemple de la *lettre de bêtises*, c'est qu'on met le doigt sur un régionalisme (Canada) où [*bêtise*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/b%C3%AAtise) peut aussi signifier « injure » (Usito) ou insulte, comme dans le syntagme *[lettre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lettre) d'insultes* (TLFi). J'y vois l'emploi de la préposition *de* afin de déterminer la teneur de la *lettre* ou comme une réduction de « rempli(e) de », ce que la lettre contient, ou c'est un peu un truc figé. Peu importe, dans ce cas-là ce serait fort différent du [*ramassis de bêtises*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51531/de-d%C3%A9terminant-partitif-vs-pr%C3%A9position#comment106972_51531) (idioties). Dans mon sociolecte, l'emploi régional complète les sens plus usuels et c'est le contexte qui fait la différence mais généralement, y recevoir une *lettre de bêtises* c'est recevoir une *lettre d'insultes* (à la manière de l'emploi régional *crier des bêtises à quelqu'un*.).

Answer (score 1):

Cette question sur la nature grammaticale de « *de* » dans l'expression « lettre de bêtises » est intéressante parce qu'en fait on peut affirmer que la notion de partitif n'est pas étrangère à cet usage particulier (« lettre de bêtises ») , bien que finalement on doive se résoudre à considérer ce mot comme une préposition et non comme un article. La perception plus ou moins intuitive que le concept de partitif est jusqu'à un certain point pertinent, tel que le mentionne le PO, est donc justifiée.  Le principe à ne pas perdre de vue en arrivant à la conclusion que, néanmoins, « de » est une préposition, s'avère être le fait élémentaire que le mot « de » est précédé par un nom ; un verbe peut établir une connexion sémantique entre deux noms, ainsi qu'une apposition, et seconde après le verbe en terme de versatilité, la préposition le peut aussi. L'article ne peut en aucun cas réaliser une connexion sémantique, qu'il soit indéfini, défini, *ou partitif*.

*Connexion par verbe et apposition*

- - Le *sac* contient **la** *farine*. - Le *sac* contient **une** *farine*. - Le *sac* contient **de la** *farine*. (*articles*)
- Le *sac, objet* très volumineux, encombrait l'espace étroit entre le comptoir et les glacières.

*Connexion par préposition*

- Le *sac* **de** *farine* était vide en une semaine.
- Le *sac* **de** la *farine* était placé sous le comptoir, celui du sel, beaucoup plus petit, était toujours dessus.
- Le *sac* **d'** une *farine* complète se trouvait à côté de celui de la farine blanche.

Pour mieux comprendre que le partitif ne peut pas servir de connexion sémantique, il faut considérer que la fonction qui est définie par les termes « article indéfini », « article défini » et « article partitif » reste inchangée, et  ne porte que sur le nom qui suit, quelle que soit la syntaxe.

- De la farine était répandue sur le sol. Il faut de la farine. C'est de la farine. La farine peut se décrire comme étant une poudre. Une farine fine convient mieux.

Il est facile de voir cela pour les articles indéfinis et définis.

- Un sac le blé  n'est pas cher. (*pas de connexion, syntaxe en erreur*)
- Un sac un blé n'est pas cher. (*pas de connexion, syntaxe en erreur*)
- Un sac du blé n'est pas cher. (*pas de connexion, mais plus difficile à voir à cause de la confusion possible entre « du », l'article défini « le » contracté avec « de », et l'article partitif masculin « du »*)

En support de l'affirmation que la notion de partitif se retrouve dans cette construction prépositionnelle, on se base sur la définition suivante du TLFi.

(C'est une définition qui peut paraitre rébarbative au premier abord, mais on peut voir par la suite qu'elle cerne bien les concepts qui confrontent le lecteur.)

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)) **I.− De prend une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec celle du mot subséquent.**
> **A.** **− *De* exprime le point de départ.**
> **6. Le point de départ est un tout dont on tire une partie.**
> a) […]
> **b) Subst. + de. *De* a une valeur partitive, proche de celle de l'article partitif.** Cf. *de*² et *des* II (en parlant d'une partie, d'un ensemble, d'un élément d'un tout).
> α) [En parlant d'un tout partageable]
> − [Le compl. est un subst. non déterminé] Tranches d'ananas; filets de sole; branche d'arbre.
> − [Le compl. est un subst. déterminé] La façade nord du transept de la cathédrale; marcher sur la pointe des pieds. Piccadilly Circus, nombril de Londres (Morand, Londres,1933, p. 173).Au pied du troisième platane de l'allée du pont (H. Bazin, Vipère,1948, p. 9).
> **β) [En parlant d'un tout nombrable, en partic. un subst. coll.]**
>
> - Une troupe d'enfants; un couple de rossignols; des escouades de motocyclistes.
> - L'âpre essaim des corbeaux voraces (Hugo, Légende,t. 3, 1877, p. 30).

Le mot subséquent (aussi « point de départ »)  est un tout *nombrable* puisque « bêtise » est au pluriel, c'est le tout de toutes les bêtises ; il est à noter qu'on pourrait trouver « bêtise » au singulier, ce qui rendrait la détermination du sens plus difficile ou impossible (« une lettre de bêtise »). La considération du tout de toutes les bêtises comme étant un *point de départ* est très générale, et elle est peut-être un peu difficile à comprendre (on ne s'y attarde pas).

On tend à comprendre que la lettre est une collection de narrations de bêtises ou bien qu'elle comporte uniquement des propos qui sont les uns après les autres des bêtises dans l'acte d'écriture de la lettre ; il n'existe pas un schéma de définition précis comme avec les noms collectifs (troupe, groupe, ensemble, …) ; si on avait utilisé le collectif « suite »  au lieu de « lettre » on penserait sans trop douter qu'il s'agit de cette dernière possibilité, et si ça avait été « liste » on serait enclin à penser qu'il s'agit de la première. Ceci montre déjà qu'on doit parler de langue relâchée. L'idée de tout partageable ne convient pas pour le concept « lettre » : une portion d'une lettre peut ne pas être une lettre. « α) » ne convient donc pas, et c'est « β) » qui est le choix le plus approprié (c'est pour cela que j'ai écrit « β) » en caractères gras mais pas « α)») ; néanmoins « lettre » n'est pas un nom collectif.

Dans le cas « lettre de bêtise » (pas d's), il n'est plus question d'un tout nombrable puisque « bêtise » change de sens et devient le nom massique qui signifie « manque d'intelligence ». Ni  « α) » ni « β) » ne conviennent assez bien pour expliquer cette construction, et elle est encore moins acceptable que la construction sans s ; la remarque similaire faite dans la réponse de [**user Timocaillou**](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51532/17649) montre que ce type de construction n'appartient pas vraiment au français. Incidemment, notons que c'est le modèle d'une expression chère à la Corse, mais que le français standard n'assimile pas : je veux parler de la construction  que l'on voit souvent sur les brochures touristiques qui ont trait à la Corse et sur les emballages de produits Corses, c'est à dire « île de beauté », par exemple en apposition comme dans « La Corse, île de beauté » (ne pas confondre avec « une île de toute beauté », construction dans laquelle « de toute beauté » est une locution idiomatique signifiant « extrêmement beau »).

On peut dire en conclusion que dans de telles constructions « de » ne prend pas de façon définie de valeur sémantique en corrélation avec le nom qui suit parce que le nom qui précède ne convient pas.